# How many straight lines are there on a torus through a finite number of points?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

> Given a finite set of points in $\Bbb{T}^2 := \Bbb{R}^2 / \Bbb{Z}^2$, when is there a straight line in $\Bbb{R}^2$ whose image under the quotient passes through all of them, and can we count how many?

I think there are either $0$ lines, countably infinite lines that become closed loops in the torus, or countably infinite lines that don't become closed loops in the torus, depending on whether the $x$ and $y$-coordinates of the points are all rational multiples of the same rational or irrational number, with a $0$-line exception made for the case when two points share the same $x$-coordinate and two points share the same $y$-coordinate.

Am I correct in believing these things? If not, what cases have I missed/gotten wrong?

Comment: Coordinates themselves are not all that important; their _differences_ are.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I thought that, but because for example (0,0) and (1,1) were 0, 1, or sqrt(2) away depending on the line you used, it seemed the coordinates were more imporant